# Powershell: -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue not working with Invoke-Expression

Tags: powershell

I am running this script

`Invoke-Expression $expression -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`

The variable `$expression` may not  have a value sometimes. When It's empty, I get the error

> Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Command' because it is null.

How can I avoid seeing the error? I want to execute Invoke-Expression regardless of `$expression` being empty, so an if statement checking that $expression has a value wouldn't work.

[image]

Comment: Have u tryed try{} catch{} yet?

Comment: this is expected behavior there is no "action" if the cmdlet doesn't even start. `function foo {[CmdletBinding()]param([ValidateNotNull()] $i) }; foo $null -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` use a try / catch block

Comment: You may cheat by appending a space: `Invoke-Expression "$expression "`

Comment: @zett42 that worked! Thank you very much. You can post it as an answer If you'd like me to accept it as solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the obligatory warning:

- `Invoke-Expression`  (`iex`) should generally be *avoided* and used only as a *last resort*, due to its inherent security risks. Superior alternatives are usually available. If there truly is no alternative, only ever use it on input you either provided yourself or fully trust - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375).

---

To add to [Mathias' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76391650/45375) and [zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42)'s simpler alternative mentioned in a comment on the question (`Invoke-Expression "$expression "`):

These solutions silence *only* the case where `$null` or an *empty string* is passed to [`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Invoke-Expression) - which may well be your intent.

To also cover the case where *all* error output should be silenced - whether due to invalid input or due to valid input causing errors during execution - the following variation is needed:

```bash
# Silences *all* errors.
try { Invoke-Expression $expression 2>$null } catch { }

# Alternative:
# Silences *all* errors and additionally *ignores* all *non-terminating* errors, 
# i.e. not only silences them, but also prevents their recording in $Error.
# By executing inside & { ... }, the effect of setting $ErrorActionPreference is 
# transitory due to executing in a *child scope*.
# Note that this also means that $expression is evaluated in the child scope.
& { $ErrorActionPreference = 'Ignore'; Invoke-Expression $expression }
```

Note:

- First command:

  - The [common `-ErrorAction` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-erroraction) fundamentally only acts on *non-terminating* errors, whereas *terminating* ones (both *statement*- and *script*-terminating ones) must be handled with a [`try` / `catch` / `finally` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally).

    - Passing `$null` or the empty string to `Invoke-Expression` causes an error *during parameter binding* (that is the, cmdlet itself is never invoked, because invalid arguments were passed), which in effect is a *statement-terminating* error - hence the need for `try` / `catch`.
    - The `try` / `catch` with the empty `catch` block additionally prevents *script*-terminating errors that result from the `Invoke-Expression` call from terminating your script too (e.g, if `$expression` contained something like `'throw "Fatal Error"'`
  - Note that `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` was replaced with `2>$null` in order to silence *non-terminating* errors (e.g., the error resulting from `Get-ChildItem NoSuchDir`), because - inexplicably - `-ErrorAction` is *not* effective with `Invoke-Expression` (even though the `-ErrorVariable` common parameter *does* work, for instance). See [GitHub issue #19734](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/19734).
- Second command:

  - Setting the [`$ErrorActionPreference` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#erroractionpreference) to `Ignore` causes *all* errors to be *silenced*, and additionally - for *non-terminating* errors only - prevents their recording in the [automatic `$Error` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#error).

    - If `-ErrorAction` worked in this case, `-ErrorAction` would have the same effect, but would act *solely* on non-terminating errors, as noted.  (This asymmetry between what should be *equivalent* mechanisms - preference variable vs. per-call common parameter, is one of the pitfalls of PowerShell's error handling - see [GitHub issue #14819](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14819)).
  - Unfortunately, (caught) *terminating* errors are *invariably* recorded in `$Error` as of PowerShell 7.3.4. From what I can tell, changing this in a future version has been green-lit a while ago, but is yet to be implemented:  see [GitHub issue #3768](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3768)
  - Using `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-) with a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) `{ ... }` executes the enclosed statements in a *child* [scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Scopes).
  - This causes `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Ignore'` to create a *local* copy of the preference variable, which automatically goes out of scope when the script block is exited, thereby implicitly restoring the previous value of `$ErrorActionPreference`.
  - However, this also means that the code executed by `Invoke-Expression` executes in that child scope.
    If that is undesired, forgo the `& { ... }` enclosure and save and restore the previous `$ErrorActionPreference` value.

Comment: That's a very complete answer, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

> How can I avoid seeing the error?

By not passing a `$null` value to `Invoke-Expression`:

```
if (-not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($expression)) {
  Invoke-Expression $expression -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
```

If you insist on invoking `Invoke-Expression`, wrap the input string in a dot-sourced scriptblock - that way `Invoke-Expression` never receives empty input:

```
Invoke-Expression ".{${expression}}" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Comment: As I said, `I want to execute Invoke-Expression regardless of $expression being empty, so an if statement checking that $expression has a value wouldn't work.`

Comment: @FranLegon You can't, but you can wrap it in something non-empty, answer updated